# @INC cannot find MOA module

Tags: perl

I have special script on our machine, which has a menu.
The script is n G drive of our server
When I try to run menu from my local C drive, I always get an error:

> Cannot locate MOA/CLSUtils.pm in @INC (you may need to install the
>   MOA::CLSUtil   Module.     @INC contains: C:/Perl/site/lib
>   C:/Perl/lib.

Do I have to install this Module on my local drive or just add it to @INC?

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to modify @INC. There are a few ways to do that, for example:

```
use lib 'G:/directory/containing/MOA/module';
use MOA::CLSUtil;
```

See @INC in the perlvar man page for more information.

You can also do that for every script by setting an environment variable, see ENVIRONMENT in the perlrun man page.

Comment: I added needed path to @INC. But now when I type "menu"    The message says :"Cannot call method Sql on undefined value at G:/INVACCT/Perl/MOA/CLSUtils.pm line 364.

Comment: @osamuylin That's a separate issue, and it requires a separate question. In your new question, be sure to post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).